# Building dynamic data table with nodeJS backend for mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, dynamic, datatable

I would like to build a data table that provides features like searching, filtering, free text search and so on (if anyone has more idea please share to create modern data table). My backend has to be in NodeJS and Front end could be simple html, css. If I need to create any middleware to make the data load faster, how will that be? Any suggestion regarding this will be very much apppreciated.
P.S: I have a mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

Building a dynamic data table with a Node.js backend for a MySQL database can be a challenge, but there are a few libraries that can help you get the job done.

One library that can be used is the [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) library. This library provides a Node.js interface for MySQL databases. It can be used to create a connection to a MySQL database, run queries, and close the connection when finished.

Another library that can be used is the [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2)/promise library. This library provides a Node.js interface for MySQL databases with promise support. It can be used to create a connection to a MySQL database, run queries, and close the connection when finished.

Finally, the [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) library can be used. This library provides an easy-to-use interface for interacting with MySQL databases. It can be used to create a connection to a MySQL database, define models, and run queries.

All of these libraries can be used to build a dynamic data table with a Node.js backend for a MySQL database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will these libraries help to create search function too? If I want to create dynamic search functionalities, how can I do that?

Comment: @shumanachowdhury The mysqljs/mysql and node-mysql2/promise libraries can be used to run queries against a MySQL database. These libraries do not provide any search functionality, but they can be used to build a custom search function. Sequelize library can be used to run queries against a MySQL database. This library provides search functionality. To use the built-in search functionality, you will need to define a model for your data. Once you have defined a model, you can call the .findAll() method and pass in a search object. The .findAll() method will return all records that match search